# How can I render AngularJs expressions on different partial views

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

### Problem:

I have been given a task to compute values from different `TextBoxes` on different `Partial Views` in `ASP .NET MVC 4` but it is not working.

For Example:

**PartialView1:**

```
TextBox1: 5
```

**PartialView2:**

```
TextBox2: 5
```

**Main View:**

```
TextBox1 + TextBox2 = 10
```

### What have I done so far...

**My PartialView 1:**

```
Number 1: <input type="number" ng-model="numberA">
```

**My PartialView 2:**

```
Number 2: <input type="number" ng-model="numberB">
```

**My Main View:**

```
<div data-ng-app="" data-ng-init="numberA=2;numberB=3">
    @Html.Partial("PartialView1", Model)
    @Html.Partial("PartialView2", Model)
    <p><b>Sum:</b> {{numberA + numberB}}</p>
</div>
```

### Question:

- Why is this not working?
- What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <div ng-init="numberA=2; numberB=3">
    <input type="number" ng-model="numberA">
    <input type="number" ng-model="numberB">
    <p><b>Sum:</b> {{numberA + numberB}}</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Where is your controller initialization on the view?
Please, use `ng-controller` directive to initialize your controller.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <div ng-init="numberA=2; numberB=3">
    <input type="number" ng-model="numberA">
    <input type="number" ng-model="numberB">
    <p><b>Sum:</b> {{numberA + numberB}}</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
}
```

This works. I have attached an example in the post.

Comment: But that's on the same view, What I want is that sum two numbers that are on two different partial views...

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi Please, provide full code, which was rendered on the view and related to this example.
Use browser console for it.

Comment: Full code is huge, I know the code is working fine, my AngularJs works fine on one page, but I am having trouble in calculating sum if I have the numbers being rendered from two different partial Views...